# How to populate <li> using JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, html-lists, htmlgenericcontrol

In my asp web application, I'm using `HtmlGenericControl` to populate a list.

Aspx code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="displayDiv" runat="server">
     <ul id="servicesList" runat="server"></ul>
</div>
```

From code Behind

```
private void LoadDisplayOrder()
{
    Service service = new Service();
    SortItem[] data = service.GetServicesDisplayOrderData();
    servicesList.Controls.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        SortItem si = data[i];
        using (HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li"))
        {
            li.Attributes.Add("class", "sortable-service-item");
            using (HtmlGenericControl spanId = new HtmlGenericControl("span"))
            {
                using (HtmlGenericControl spanName = new HtmlGenericControl("span"))
                {
                    using (HtmlGenericControl dragHandel = new HtmlGenericControl("span"))
                    {
                        spanId.InnerText = si.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                        dragHandel.Attributes.Add("class", "drag-handle-container");
                        dragHandel.InnerHtml = "<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>";
                        serviceIds.Add(si.Id);
                        spanId.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none;");
                        spanName.InnerText = si.Name;
                        li.Controls.Add(dragHandel);
                        li.Controls.Add(spanId);
                        li.Controls.Add(spanName);
                        servicesList.Controls.Add(li);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This populating List without any problem. now I need to generate list as same behaviour by using javascript. In above code data is a array with `Id` and `Name`. I have same JSON string look like this.

```
{
   "Id":1,
   "Name":"Doe"
},
{
   "Id":2,
   "Name":"Smith"
},
{
   "Id":3,
   "Name":"Jones"
}
```

I need to populate `<li>` by using Javascript same as what I generated `<li>` by using C#  `HtmlGenericControl`. how can I do this? How to add attributes, styles, class using javascript while genearting `<li>`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down into different steps:

**Parsing JSON**

I made a test string of your sample JSON and just called the built in javascript command to parse it and store it in an array. (*Make sure your JSON is a valid JSON array - wrapped in square brackets [ ].*)

```
var json = "[ { \"Id\":1, \"Name\":\"Doe\" }, { \"Id\":2, \"Name\":\"Smith\" }, 
              { \"Id\":3, \"Name\":\"Jones\" } ]";

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

**Looping through JSON Array to add new li elements to ul**

Reference different objects in the array by calling `array[index].Property`. Add a `TextNode` to set the text of the `li`

```
var list = document.getElementById('<%= servicesList.ClientID %>');

for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[i].Name));    
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```

**Setting attributes - in loop**

Inside your loop, you can set the `className` and other attributes pretty easily.

```
li.className = "myClass";
li.setAttribute("data-id", obj[i].Id);
```

Hope this helps.

---

**Whole test sample:**

```
var json = "[ { \"Id\":1, \"Name\":\"Doe\" }, { \"Id\":2, \"Name\":\"Smith\" }, 
              { \"Id\":3, \"Name\":\"Jones\" } ]";

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var list = document.getElementById('<%= servicesList.ClientID %>');

for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[i].Name));
    li.className = "myClass";
    li.setAttribute("data-id", obj[i].Id);
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```